# Linux Find command hangs

Tags: linux

The find command is as below:

find / -path "/proc/*" -prune -o -iname "*core.*"|grep -i "core\.[0-9]"|grep -v "\.gz"|grep -v "/man/"

It works well in our many labs, finished within a few minutes. But in another lab, it hangs over 1 hour.

Checked the output of "top" and "iostat -x -k" in that lab. The CPU and I/O load on that lab looks normal, but the find command is in **S** status.

------------top-------------

4203 root      15   0  652m 500m  636 **S**  9.7  1.6 148:34.69 find

---

Any hint/idea is appreciated.

Comment: Attach to a process with `strace` and see where it sleeps

Comment: This question likely belongs to http://superuser.com site.

Comment: @skwllsp there is no strace command in that lab.

Comment: Then try ti attach with `gdb`

Comment: @skwllsp, still no command gdb :(

Comment: Then do `cat /proc/<PID>/stack`, where <PID> is the `find` process id. And `cat /proc/<PID>/syscall`

Comment: You can read this article http://blog.tanelpoder.com/2013/02/21/peeking-into-linux-kernel-land-using-proc-filesystem-for-quickndirty-troubleshooting/ in order to find out how you can use this info

Comment: I'd remove the `/*` from `/proc/*`. I'd also prune /sys. I also think there should be a `-print` at the end of the `find` command, before the pipe.

Comment: @skwllsp, thanks very much. I'll digest your article first then check on that lab.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the root cause. It's caused by a extremely huge directory.

[root@tt-na01-as01 export]# ll

drwxrwxr-x 2 system sysop **756490240** Nov 5 16:24 com.nsn.app.nbm.pm3gpp-1

The directory is so huge that even 'ls' and 'rm' commands hang.

Any suggestion on how to delete huge directory?